# How do I add an identifier to auto layout anchor constraints?

Tags: ios, swift, debugging, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I want to add identifiers to all my constraints so I can debug an issue. The problem is that I don’t create all my constraints directly if I use anchors.
I can create a constraint:

```
 let constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 60.0)
```

but then I’d have to add it to the view, not the heightAnchor (there is no .addConstraint() method associated with UIStackViews)

So how do I add identifiers to the constraints auto-generated by these lines of code:

```
    view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60.0).isActive = true
    view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60.0).isActive = true
```

anchors are supposed to make programming auto layout easier, but surely not at the expense of being unable to debug properly?
If I can’t add identifiers, how do I debug my “unsatisfiable” constraints exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code returns you constraint, so you can add identifier to it like this

```
let myConstraint = view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60.0)
myConstraint.identifier = "myIdentifier"
myConstraint.isActive = true
```

Comment: Ah. I thought it was creating multiple constraints (an array of them perhaps). Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Look at the answer I gave in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42392072/programming-autolayout-swift/42392533#42392533). It will give you an answer to your question.

> (there is no .addConstraint() method

Yes, there is:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([constraintvariable])
```

**Edit:**

Alright, if I understand your question correctly:

```
let vHeightConstraint = self.view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60.0);
vHeightConstraint.isActive = true
vHeightConstraint.identifier = "Your identifier"
```

This way you'll have a variable for you constraint and that will be available under debugging to see it's value.

Comment: I edited my question to clarify the point that these new anchor constraints don't have an .addConstraint() method.  I understand how to activate constraints. I want to avoid having to manually create and activate additional constraints when auto layout has already created them using .heightAnchor, .widthAnchor, etc. These anchors are supposed to reduce the amount of code, not require duplication of efforts.

Comment: I saw NSDmitry's response before this most recent edit. I upvoted this as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I use arrays and activate/deactivate them:

```
var p = [NSLayoutConstraint]() // portrait constraints
var l = [NSLayoutConstraint]() // landscape constraints

// (an example of this) pin segmentedView to top

p.append(segmentedControl.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageLayout.topAnchor))
p.append(segmentedControl.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300))
p.append(segmentedControl.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageLayout.centerXAnchor))
l.append(segmentedControl.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageLayout.topAnchor))
l.append(segmentedControl.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300))
l.append(segmentedControl.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageLayout.centerXAnchor))

public func setOrientation(_ p:[NSLayoutConstraint], _ l:[NSLayoutConstraint]) {
    NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(l)
    NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(p)
    if self.bounds.width > self.bounds.height {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(l)
    } else {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(p)
    }
}
```

You get the idea.... move your constraints into an array and activate/deactivate as needed.

Comment: Very nice, indeed! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have a different approach using Swift 4.2. I hope that may be useful.

```
extension UIView{

    func getConstraint(forAttribute attribute:NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute)->NSLayoutConstraint?{

        for aConstraint in constraints{

            if aConstraint.firstAttribute == attribute{

                return aConstraint

            }

        }

        return nil

    }

}
```

so you can do;

```
@IBOutlet weak var confirmButton: MainButton!{
    didSet{
        confirmButton.getConstraint(forAttribute: .height)!.identifier = aID
        confirmButton.isEnabled = false
    }
}
```

or

```
myOtherButton.getConstraint(forAttribute: .height)?.identifier = "newIdentifier"
```

Comment: Thank you, It it is quite straight forward and gives you a lot of control!